# asp.net web api returns nothing when the list is populated

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I'm trying to return a list of objects from the controller's get method 
but it returns an empty json or an xml that just says the object type repeatedly
here's my code

```
         ...
         ...
public List<Project> Get()
        {

         ...
         ...
         ...
         foreach (DataRow row in projectsDT.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
              row_current = new Project();
              row_current.fill(row,i);
              projectlist.Add(row_current);
              i++;
            }
            return projectlist;
        }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you provide more information about your code? What is row_current and projectlist type? If your are getting a object type repeatedly, probably you have a .ToString() in somewhere. If you show all your Get method I'll be glad to help.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to answer your question. In fact, it is not even clear what the question is you are asking,

Comment: thanks for responding , that file is here :
 https://github.com/Maioy97/webbasedCV_backend/blob/master/webapi/webapi/Controllers/ValuesController.cs